# C# Select from a table with changed schema filling missing columns with null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, linq

I'm trying to create a method that select all columns from a database table and fills in missing columns with null. That is if I run my program on an old version of the database table it fills in the missing columns with null values.

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do/have done in this scenario is create a database project for my most up to date database which will generate a dacpac.  After you have that you can do an update based off the schema doing something like this.

```
            var dp = DacPackage.Load(file.FullName);
            var dbDeployOptions = new DacDeployOptions
            {

                DropObjectsNotInSource = false,
                DropRoleMembersNotInSource = false,
                DropPermissionsNotInSource = false,
                ScriptDatabaseOptions = false,
                BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false,
                IgnoreExtendedProperties = true,
                IgnoreFileAndLogFilePath = false,
                IgnoreLoginSids = true,
                GenerateSmartDefaults = true,
                TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings = true,
                VerifyDeployment = true,
                CommandTimeout = 600
            };
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder constring = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sqlconnstring.Text);
            var dbServices = new DacServices(sqlconnstring.Text);

            try
            {
                dbServices.Deploy(dp, constring.InitialCatalog, true, dbDeployOptions);
            }
```